# How to call up the argument passed to the View?

Tags: 7, views

I have a view that reads the argument from panel url.

How can I call up the passed argument inside the "no result case" with html code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible with HTML, but 'No result case' allows you to use PHP, so arg(x) should work, x being the zero based position of your argument in the URL.